# How to create a postfix button in Twitter-bootstrap for rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, button

I recently switched from `Foundation Zurb` , to `Twitter bootstrap for Rails`.

And in `Foundation Zurb` , the postfix button was already provided within the existing options, which is not the case for `twitter-bootstrap-rails`.

I tried doing stuff like this

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <f.text_area :search, :class => "text_area">
    <%= button_tag "name", type: 'button', class: "btn btn-info"%>
</div>
```

But I could not seem to even go near it.

Can anyone provide some useful method to do this?

Ps : *For those of you who do not know what is a postfix button, it is exactly as the button that is in Youtube for instance, Next to the search bar.
Check this [link](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html) and scroll down to Pre/post fix buttons ,and you'll see what I am talking about.*

**======================================**

A look into my gemfile as requested by @Sadik

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.2'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'less-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# User ActiveModel act_as_list
gem 'acts_as_list', '~> 0.4.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

#Use ActiveModel geocoded_by :address after_validation :geocode
 gem 'geocoder'

#User SCSSS for Stylesheets
 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

===============================================

Update #1 : **Solved**

Thanks to the answer below, but not really the answer, thanks to the comment that specified that I should update to the right version of twitter-bootstrap.

If you are facing the same problem, Go to your gemfile and write

```
 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', github: 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails', branch: 'bootstrap3'
```

And `bundle install` and Absolutely then `rails g bootstrap:install less` to the end of story that you already know.

For further support, check this [link](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/bootstrap3)

Comment: can you show the relevant part of your Gemfile?

Comment: what you mean by postfix button? is it a normal button or what?

Comment: you mean button addons I guess http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I used the code in there but it's not working, It can be due to my gem version, I am pretty sure that version 3 isn't available for rails users yet, can you provide any other solution?

Comment: I am using version 3 as a gem and it works. A little googling around won't hurt you.

Comment: I bet you are talking about bootstrap-sass, whilst I am talking about Twitter-bootstrap. am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Bootstrap input group addon is what you are looking for change your code to

```
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= f.text_field :search, :class => "form-control" %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/monideeps99/2Ag3g/

Comment: It's not working for twitter-bootstrap. I guess I'll have to switch to bootstrap.

Comment: I guess its not working because you are using bootstrap version 2 for version 3 use use the bootstrap3 branch. change your gemfile to <code> gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', github: 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails', branch: 'bootstrap3' </code>